# In the Word Navigation pane, all headings below Heading 2 style are indented by the same amount. How can I further indent Heading 3 and Heading 4?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, indent

In Office 365 Word, I can format the Heading styles in the document and indent them as I require. In the Navigation pane however, all headings (below Heading 2) are indented by the same amount. It would improve the legibility if these were also indented further to reflect their heirarchy. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which Word version?

Comment: Is this the Online version, the Mac version, the Windows version? In my experience, each level has a bit more indenting. This is not something that the user can adjust.

Comment: This is in the Windows version.